# Bootstrap 4 - hidden classes - only hide on small screens

Tags: bootstrap-4

How to hide `span` content only on small (sm) screens? I need this content visible on `xs` screens.

```
<span class="hidden-sm-down">Text</span>
```

There is a way to do this using only bootstrap classes or not?

Comment: Welcome to [so], try to search here and google before you post the question.  You may go to search `@media` and study it.

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for your reply. I did search but didn't find any useful info about it, I guess it's because bootstrap 4 is in alpha yet. Also I read the [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities) and realized that they only present a way to only **show** in some screen resolutions. So, I would appreciate any help

Comment: reading the docs again found that may not be achieved using bootstrap classes and must be done by myself, thanks anyway

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With Bootstrap 4 Beta 1, you can hide `sm` only with `d-block d-sm-none d-md-block`.

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/bootstrap/bootstrap-hide-element-based-on-viewport-size/

Answer (score 38):

There is an upcoming update for Bootstrap 4 that will enable hidden on a single viewport (`hidden-x`)..

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22113

All of the visibility classes will be revamped in this update.

---

**Update for Bootstrap 4 Beta**

If you want to hide an element on specific tiers (breakpoints) in Bootstrap 4, use the `d-*` display classes accordingly. Remember `xs` is the default (always implied) breakpoint, unless overridden by a *larger* breakpoint.

https://www.codeply.com/go/bRlHp8MxtJ

- `hidden-xs-down` = `d-none d-sm-block`
- `hidden-sm-down` = `d-none d-md-block`
- `hidden-md-down` = `d-none d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg-down` = `d-none d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl-down` = `d-none` (same as `hidden`)
- `hidden-xs` (only) = `d-none d-sm-block` (same as `hidden-xs-down`)
- `hidden-sm` (only) = `d-block d-sm-none d-md-block`
- `hidden-md` (only) = `d-block d-md-none d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg` (only) = `d-block d-lg-none d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl` (only) = `d-block d-xl-none`

[Demo of all hidden / visible classes in Bootstrap 4 beta](https://www.codeply.com/go/bRlHp8MxtJ)

Also note that `d-*-block` can be replaced with `d-*-inline`, `d-*-flex`, etc.. depending on the display type of the element. More on the [display classes in beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32)

Comment: official docs can be found here: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Answer (score 7):

It's quite easy. All you have to know is, how to use bootstrap 4 classes properly.

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

First think as it's divide into three ordered groups. (When some group is not applicable omit that group)

```
(hide_lower_limit) (display_size) (hide_upper_limit)
```

1. `(hide_lower_limit)`: has  only one class `.d-none`
2. `(display_size)`: sizes to be visible (not-hide), eg: `.d-sm-block`, `.d-md-block`. It will have a format of `.d-<size>-block`
3. `(hide_upper_limit)`: the upper limit which should be hidden. This has a format of `.d-<size+1>-none`

---

**Let's look into some examples**

Q1: Display on `md` and bigger.

ans:

Start with visible screen size, `(display_size)`: `.d-md-block`.

Then think of all screen sizes which should be hidden, ie, all screen sizes

- smaller than `md` hidden, `(hide_lower_limit)`: `.d-none`
- bigger than `md` not hidden, `(hide_upper_limit)`: `<omit>`

> d-none d-md-block

Q2: Display on `sm` and smaller.

ans: 
`(display_size)`: `.d-sm-block`.

Hidden screen sizes

- smaller than `sm` not hidden, `(hide_lower_limit)`: `<omit>`
- bigger than `sm` hidden, `(hide_upper_limit)`: `.d-md-none`

> d-sm-block d-md-none

Q3: Visible only in `sm` and `md`.

ans: 
`(display_size)`: `.d-sm-block .d-md-block`.

Hidden screen sizes

- smaller than `sm` hidden, `(hide_lower_limit)`: `.d-none`
- bigger than `sm` hidden, `(hide_upper_limit)`: `.d-lg-none`

> d-none d-md-block d-sm-block d-lg-none

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs again found that may not be achieved using bootstrap classes and must be done by myself

So I ended up by doing this:

imported `mixins` and `variables` from bootstrap and

```css
@each $bp in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  .visible-#{$bp}-up {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($bp) {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
  .visible-#{$bp}-down {
    @include media-breakpoint-down($bp) {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're just trying to show a span on xs-screens only can't you just use `<span class="visible-xs-block"></span>`? docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Asher, but I'm using Bootstrap v4, and there is no `visible-*` classes anymore

Comment: So, according to the table here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes `hidden-sm-up` shows only on xs devices. Guess this didn't work.

Comment: It works as expected, but not fits my needs, cuz I need it to only be hidden on small screens