# Bootstrap 4 how to hide div at medium only

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to know how to hide a div in medium screen only? 
I have tried many combinations, but none of them worked
is there any class which can hide MD only with adding custom css?

Comment: please add code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 - hidden classes - only hide on small screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476201/bootstrap-4-hidden-classes-only-hide-on-small-screens)

Answer (score 4):

[Bootstrap 4 beta dropped the support for hidden-* classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities). It was replaced in favor of the d-classes (display).

If you want to show an item only at a spesific breakpoint and above, you can do:

```
<span class="d-none d-xl-inline">
   Here is some text that will only display at extra large displays, 1200px or above.
</span>
```

---

The other way (which is simpler): Only show an item if the view port is smaller than an extra large display:

```
<span class="d-xl-none">
   Here is some text that will display up until extra large displays, 1200px, but not wider.
</span>
```

You can switch the display type of `d-xl-inline` to any of [bootstraps supported d-classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/).

Also, here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476201/bootstrap-4-hidden-classes-only-hide-on-small-screens).

Answer (score 3):

This is the same issue as explained [this question to hide only on small viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476201/bootstrap-4-hidden-classes-only-hide-on-small-screens). There is an upcoming update for Bootstrap 4 Beta that will enable hidden on a single viewport (hidden-x)..

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22113

All of the visibility classes will be revamped in this update.

**Update for Bootstrap 4 Beta**

If you want to hide an element on specific tiers (breakpoints) in Bootstrap 4 Beta, use the `d-*` display classes accordingly. Remember `xs` is the default (always implied) breakpoint, unless overridden by a *larger* breakpoint.

- `hidden-xs` (only) = `d-none d-sm-block` (same as `hidden-xs-down`)
- `hidden-sm` (only) = `d-block d-sm-none d-md-block`
- `hidden-md` (only) = `d-block d-md-none d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg` (only) = `d-block d-lg-none d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl` (only) = `d-block d-xl-none`

[Demo of all hidden / visible classes in Bootstrap 4 beta](https://www.codeply.com/go/bRlHp8MxtJ)

Also note that `d-*-block` can be replaced with `d-*-inline`, `d-*-flex`, etc.. depending on the display type of the element. More on the [display classes in beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32)